# Why is the episode called "The Last of the Starks"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, title

The latest episode of *Game of Thrones* Season 8, episode 4 has been named "The Last of the Starks". Why was it named so? I couldn't fathom the reason behind this intriguing episode title.

Comment: That's a much better title than I saw. On HBO Now last night, it was just titled *Game of Thrones 71*. All the other episodes had titles, though.

Comment: @Geobits They hide the episode titles for at least the first day to avoid spoilers.  All of the episodes this season have received the same treatment.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's related to the scene below when Jon is talking to Sansa, Arya and Bran, those are the last of the starks. Arya even says those words:

> Arya: We are family, the four of us, **The last of the Starks**.

[image: last of the starks]

Comment: This doesn't answer why the episode was titled the Last of the Starks though. It doesn't explaining any thematic meaning if at all

Comment: @KharoBangdo I mean, it's pretty obvious by the scene, no? It's the last of the starks alive, they are family...

Comment: Also because as few as they are, their numbers keep dwindling further. Jon is not _really_ a Stark. Bran is now the Three-Eyed Raven, has stopped calling himself a Stark. Arya cares deeply about her family, but the Stark lordship is something she wants no part of. And Sansa's stuck in the North, away from pivotal events. The role of "House Stark" in the story has, in its capacities as a house, come to a low.

Comment: To make things worse they could be the last generation of Starks, Jon Snow is not a Stark by name, both Arya and Sansa would normally take their husbands name in marriage so any children would have their name and Bran seems unlikely or may be unable to father children of his own.

Comment: @detuur Jon's mom is a Stark. He's just as much of a Stark as before, only it's via his mom's side, not dad's.

Comment: @Sarriesfan House Karstark is of Stark patrilinear blood, they might be able to continue the ... oh, wait, nevermind.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Patrilinearity for the "win". As / if Jon's heritage becomes common knowledge (I don't watch GoT, I don't know how many know his real name yet), he's effectively the last *of the Targaryen*...

Comment: @DevSolar - True, and I was going to mention that (to paraphrase from the latest episode, "roosters matter"), but as far as his siblings go, I'd say he's as much a Stark as they are.

Comment: @BruceWayne but the rest of Westeros society would consider him a Tagaryen even if his cousins ( as they really are) regard him as a Stark.

Comment: Does she really say that???  Seems odd they would ALL have completely forgotten about Rickon.

Comment: @TabAlleman I've got some bad news for you... See GoT 59 (or episode 6.9): Battle of the Bastards.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't probably pay attention.  Towards the end I was just like, well, they're all alive, why the name! It's a dialogue and the lineage considered.

Answer (score 37):

Sansa, Arya and Bran find out that they are the last of the Starks in this episode, because Jon is not actually Eddard Stark's son. He is a Targaryen, and his children would be Targaryens.

Sansa and Arya are women, so would take their husband's names and their children would not be called Stark. Bran doesn't consider himself to be Bran Stark anymore, having become the Three-Eyed Raven, and seems unlikely to have children.

Therefore there will not be another generation of Stark children, and the house will cease to exist. Eddard Stark's remaining children are the last of their name.

Comment: very good answer!, not only the last remaining starks today, but assumable the last starks ever...

Comment: Well, inside the GoT universe (just like in the middle ages) it's possible for a woman of a high house to marry a lord of a smaller house as to keep the lineage alive. Sansa can do this but I don't think it will be covered in the show

Comment: Nice Answer, and a nice contrast to mine! +1

Comment: In the books it is mentioned that current Stark lineage is not paternally connected to the founder. There were at least one time when it's linked only via woman of Stark line (unnamed daughter of Brandon the Daughterless, which had a son with Bael the Bard).

Comment: Rickon is a surviving male Stark

Comment: @TabAlleman: Rickon was killed by Ramsay Bolton.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but Bran didn't find out that Jon isn't a stark this past episode; he already knew that. It was just Sansa and Arya who found out (in addition to Tyrion, Varys, and basically everyone else now that Varys knows).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I didn't consider the fact that they mean that the lineage ends with this generation. I was like they're all here ans alive why is this such a big thing. Jon technically is a Targ. It's always been hes a half stark in my mind, but tech. hes a stark. Sansa and Arya if married will no longer be starks (I dont know if Sansa inspite of being married hasn't taken up the Bolton's or Lannister names) .. Bran, well hes technically a Stark, but really hes kind of everyone now. Loved both the answers, two different approaches. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the possibility of Sansa marrying a candidate from a lesser house and keeping her name. Littlefinger was also only lord protector of the Vale by marriage, not lord of the Vale.

Comment: _"Sansa and Arya are women, so would take their husband's names and their children would not be called Stark."_ This just simply isn't correct, woman in GoT do not always take their husbands name, see Cersei Lannister as one main prominent example.

Comment: @user28434 Also, by precedent, Sansa and Arya's children can take the name Stark legally. Similarly, any man they marry can take the name Stark as well. People however usually change names only when they are about to inherit something. Like King Joffrey Lydden became King Joffrey Lannister when his father-in-law King Gerold III Lannister died.

Comment: anyways, instead of rehashing it all here, [See my older answer here for details](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134306/54887)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot but her kids are called Baratheon. Phrasing might be off, but the point about their offspring still stands.

Comment: @JAD Well see Aegon's comments for that point. And of course they were named Baratheon's in name only.

Answer (score 2):

Someone actually answers this in the episode when they say that Bran is now rightful Lord of Winterfell but he doesn't want it. Inheritance goes through the male line only.